# Iterating a row with 2 columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a component that will receive some data (array of strings) and will build a nice table of divs (product is just a strings):

```
      <div className="container">
        {data.map((product, i) => (
          <div className="row" key={i}>
            <div className="column">
                {product}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

The problem is that in my code it creates a new column (with a {product} in it) for each new row.
How can I make it that 2 columns (with 2 products total, 1 product each column) will be created for each 1 row?

Comment: Is `product` an object or array or something that would require two columns?

Comment: @Nick so consider data as an array of strings, and a product is just a string. Like a name of a product or something.

Comment: I see. So why would you need two columns? To add another column, wouldn't you want to have data to put in it?

Comment: @Nick exactly. I want to have a row, and then column with {product}, then another column with {product}, and a new row starting with another 2 columns with 2 products till iteration is over.

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll work on an answer, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the map function to return only on even indexes, and 2 columns a time.

```
<div className="container">
  {data.map((product, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      return (
        <div className="row" key={i}>
          <div className="column">{product}</div>
          {data[i + 1] ? (
            <div className="column">{data[i + 1]}</div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly with array of strings, and it seems as the simplest answer so I have the last question: instead of array of strings, is it possible with array of objects? (with Object.keys or something else?)

Comment: It doesn't matter. if you have array of objects, you probally want to change the content inside a column, or make column as another component. It's up to you.

Comment: @wxsm, so in case I get data from an object, I use Object.keys(this.props.data) in order to get the keys and render the data. But it shows me only name and color.  Maybe it's the problem with the Object.keys ? It works perfectly with only array of string. That's how the object looks like: {
            "name": "tv",
            "size": "big",
            "color": "grey",
            "country": "japan",
        }

Comment: If I wasn't clear, basically instead of that array of strings you tried for yourself with your code, try to iterate through a normal data you will get from JSON... How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

First some logic to convert you string array into an array of arrays:

```js
const data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

const products = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc.length || acc[acc.length - 1].length === 2) {
    acc.push([]);
  }
  acc[acc.length - 1].push(el);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(products);
```

Now assuming you've done that somewhere in your component, we can use our array of arrays to display the products:

```
<div className="container">
  {products.map(col => (
    <>
      <div className="row" key={i}>
        <div className="column">{col[0]}</div>
        {col[1] && <div className="column">{col[1]}</div>}
      </div>
    </>
  ))}
</div>;
```

I added in a quick check to make sure the last element of the array had a value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To Iterating a row with 2 columns

If you want to go through each row  of table, knowing the row(), and iterate through each column() of each row(), then this is the way to go.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table1.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
   }  
}
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is it possible to run this code inside of render() in React.js ?